# why are certain nodes of my cassandra cluster steadily growing in size?

Tags: cassandra

I have a 48 node C* cluster (3.11.4) spread across 4 AWS regions with RF=3. A few months ago I started noticing disk usage on some nodes increasing consistently. At first I solved the problem by destroying the nodes and rebuilding them, but the problem returns.

I did some more investigation recently, and this is what I found:
- I narrowed the problem down to a CF that uses TWCS (and all rows written have a ttl), by simply looking at disk space usage
- in each region, 3 nodes have this problem of growing disk space (matches replication factor)
- on each node, I tracked down the problem to a particular SSTable using `sstableexpiredblockers`. This one SSTable is blocking all of the other SSTables from being cleaned up
- in the SSTable, using `sstabledump`, I found a row that does not have a ttl like the other rows, and appears to be from someone else on the team testing something and forgetting to include a ttl
- all other rows show "expired: true" except this one, hence my suspicion
- when I query for that particular partition key, I get no results
- I tried deleting the row anyways, but that didn't seem to change anything
- I also tried `nodetool scrub`, but that didn't help either

Would this rogue row without a ttl explain the problem? If so, why? If not, does anyone have any other ideas? Why does the row show in `sstabledump` but not when I query for it?

I appreciate any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by performing a major compaction on the CF.

Here is my understanding of why this worked:

- TWCS stores data in time windows, and when all data is expired in an sstable it will drop the whole file. TWCS will not compact sstables in different time windows
- writing data without a ttl means that you can't drop the sstable, because it has some data that isn't expired. even deleting it isn't enough, because deleting the row only creates a tombstone in another sstable
- cassandra will only perform minor compactions automatically for performance reasons, so that means it will never be able to compact away the dead data in this case

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is the definition of your schema, to be more precise, the partition key, as you may have a larger portion of records that are assigned to few tokens, this condition is known as "hotspots".

For example, let's imagine that your table has information of cars, and your partition token is the country where it is located, the nodes that are assigned to hold data of cars from the USA or Germany will have a bigger amount of data [compared to the ones that have the tokens for cars in Bangladesh or Pakistan](https://www.statista.com/statistics/516280/share-of-households-that-own-a-passenger-vehicle-by-country/)

You may want to use a composite partition key, aiming for an even distribution of the shards of your data.

Comment: a hotspot wouldn't explain why the data continues to grow, because everything that is written has a ttl (I tried to make that more clear in the question, the ttl is ~1 day). This being caused by a hotspot would imply that there is ever more data being written for the given partition key, in which case there would be plenty of 'large partition' warnings in the logs. It also wouldn't explain the `sstableexpiredblockers` issue showing that one particular SSTable is blocking the other SSTables from dropping

Comment: I'm sorry to disagree, but we are talking about different topics. TTL refers to how long the data is kept in the cluster, and not how it is being distributed across the cluster, as does the partition key.

Please also note setting the TTL won't necessary decrease disk utilization, as first you'll need to wait for the `gr_grace_seconds` period before the data can be removed with a compaction. The default is 10 days

Comment: `gc_grace_seconds` is set to 0. I understand what you're saying, but my point is that even if all data was being written to the same partition, if all the data has the same ttl then you would expect the data size to remain constant, not continue to grow over time (unless the rate of data being written is always increasing). Am I missing something?

Comment: setting `gc_grace_seconds` to zero disables hinted handoffs on your cluster, which decreases the resilience of the cluster to hardware failures https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/03/21/hinted-handoff-gc-grace-demystified.html